# How can I have a view reset when an exposed title filter is emptied?

Tags: views

I have a view that simply lists content. I have one exposed filter "Title" for users to filter content that "contains" and text they insert. I have set the exposed filter to Autosubmit as they type with ajax turned on. The problem is that if the user deletes what they have added to the exposed title filter, the view isn't reset. It stills shows the results of their previous submission. I can of course add a reset button but is there any way to have the view reset itself when the exposed title filter is emptied by the user?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add jQuery to listen on the textfield change event, or similar. If value is empty then set location to current path without querystring. YMMV